# File-based HSQLDB does not track call next value on sequence

Tags: java, sequence, hsqldb

If I have a file-based HSQLDB instance and I try to get some raw sequence values into my java code:

```
JdbcTemplate(dataSource).queryForObject("call next value for mysequence", int.class)
```

Then when I restart the database I see the following line in db.script:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE PUBLIC.MYSEQUENCE RESTART WITH 1
```

That means each time I restart, MYSEQUENCE begins again at 1 irrespective of how many times call next value is invoked outside a DML statement.

If the next value for mysequence is invoked as part of an update or insert, then the RESTART WITH looks correct in the db.script file.

What could I be doing wrong?

(follow up: I've tried the same idiom in Derby and, apart from a minor issue where an unexpected DB shutdown will cause the sequence to start after the previously pre-allocated value, rather than the next value, it works as expected. H2 works as expected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should execute the `SHUTDOWN` statement to close the database. This should persist the sequence value.

Comment: Many thanks fredt, I'll mark your answer as accepted. As a side-note, if the process is killed then the database would be in a bad state.